# How to exceed screen max resolution

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution

Is there a way to exceed my old's lcd screen 1280 x 1025 max resolution, on windows 10 - 64 bit? Nothing extreme but I would like to go for a 4:3 1440 x 1080 (or around that area) for a particular program that needs it to work properly.
I know more modern screens are cheap and mine is obsolete, but before I get rid of it, I would like to know if there is a way. Any application or program or trick?
I'm using RYZEN 3 native graphic card Radeon Vega 8. No super resolution support for this one as far as I know.
Thank you.

Comment: Max is max, no way to go beyond this.

Comment: Super resolution is the only way to go beyond what a monitor is capable of, but even then, the monitor is still at 1280x1024 so the upscaled version is a bit fuzzy. Other ways to achieve super resolution without a card supporting it are very slow and not worth the trouble. Really you are better of replacing the monitor.

Comment: In case I wanted to try what is an ok way to achieve super resolution even if it's slow? Just for experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Every display has a certain amount of pixels horizontaly and vertically. You cannot use more than these.